# Why does the function in the event polling loop trigger less frequently than the function outside it

Tags: c++, c, opengl, sdl

I have a cube that rotates by itself and one that rotates when a key is being pressed. The problem is that the one that rotates by itself always rotates faster(much faster) than the one that rotates only when a key is being pressed.

```
while(!quit())
{
  handleInput();
  update();
  render();
}
```

When I put my rotation here:

```
update()
{
  cube.rotation += 0.09f;
}
```

The cube rotates fast.
But when i put it here:

```
handleinput()
{
   while(pollevent(&event))
   {
      if(event.type == keydown)
      {
        if(event.key.symbol == KEY_r )
        {
           cube.rotation += 0.09f;
        }
      }
   }
```

It is much slower. Though I assume that both should be getting called once each loop when the key is being held down.
And I don't know what this question must be tagged.

Comment: I'm guessing events are coming in way slower that your main loop iterates?

Comment: Your computer probably has setting for the "repeat rate" of keys. That's your limit in the second case. (Even if it doesn't have a setting, your OS has a limited repeat rate.)

Comment: I used some `cout`s and noticed that the event poll loop runs only once while the main loop runs more than 5 times when a key is being pressed down. Is it a problem of the `pollevent` function ?

Comment: @Elvisjames It's a problem with how you understand "keydown" - it doesn't mean "the key is down", it means "the key has transitioned to a down state". The OS usually fires this event repeatedly (with a delay) for the purpose of typing many characters by holding down the key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `keydown` event is simply *fired* less frequently than your game logic is updated.

A common solution is to keep track of the keyboard's state.

### SDL way

I suggest storing the  keyboard state as an array of booleans, which size is the number of keys you will check against, e.g. `bool[SDL_KEYLAST]`.
So you'll have to modify it whenever an event is fired. Finally, at each loop, check for the saved keyboard state.
Example code:

```
handleInput()
{
    while(pollEvent(&ev))
    {
        if(event.type = keydown)
            ks[event.key.symbol] = true;
        else if(event.type = keyup)
            ks[event.key.symbol] = false;
    }
}

update()
{
    if(ks[KEY_R]) cube.rotation += 0.05f;
}
```

### SDL2 way

`const Uint8* ks = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL)`.

This function returns the keyboard state array, which is not a `bool[]` but a `Uint8[]` containing 0/1 values (so you can still check on false/true values).

But also, you'll have to check against `SDL_Scancode` index values if you want to use that array, which are listed here: https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Scancode

```
handleinput()
{
    //pump events so that SDL can update the keyboard state array...
}

update()
{
    const Uint8* ks = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);
    if(ks[SDL_SCANCODE_R]) cube.rotation += 0.05f;
}
```

Reference: https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetKeyboardState

Answer (score 0):

dmg is likely correct.

Pollevent doesn't just iterate over a list of keys currently pressed, you're iterating over a list of events to handle, and it only gets updated at your repeat rate. You probably want to internally handle the state of the button, and toggle it on and off with the events, handling the rotation in the update (better separation of functionality, anyway).